# Modificar longitud de línea VSCODE

Tags: javascript, vscode

Estoy trabajando con un texto estructurado en forma de array con 10000 registros numericos, este texto lo copio desde una pagina web(lo regresa una API), luego necesito hacer pruebas en mi VSCODE con esta información.

Cuando pegue este texto en un archivo.js en vscode, se veía de color blanco, luego trabaje los saltos de línea hasta lograr que el texto se viera de color amarillo; finalmente coloque unas comillas al principio y al final para pasarlo a string (texto de color naranja), pero no funciona.

Dejo una imagen de como se ve.
La pregunta es ¿Como puedo transformar el texto como cadena? i.e.
let string = "texto en formato array"

[image: texto en formato numerico con espacios entre numeros]

Gracias.

Comment: La api no te dice en que tipo de formato te lo esta devolviendo?, porque tal cual como esta parece ser octal, pero no estoy seguro.

Comment: Buena pregunta, ya revise el URL query string, dice "text-plain". Saludos

Comment: Por cierto en VSCode existe una opción llamada toggle line wrap, te ayuda a evitarte tener que dar enter a cada rato, para ello primero selecciona la linea, y luego dale toggle line wrap, o asi mas menos se llama, sin embargo no recuerdo en que opción del menu de VSCode  se encuentra... normalmente no la uso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a todos x sus respuestas.

Se hizo trabajo manual, agregando un caracter de escape "\" al final de cada linea:[image: inicio de la cadena de numeros con primer slash]
Y asi para cada una (ugh!!!)....................................................:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se agrega una coma para cerrar, asi se forma el string gigante, y ya se puede usar en variables.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No vote en contra, por que me parecio una pregunta totalmente valida, sin embargo creo que podrias hacer eso mismo que hiciste sin necesidad de colocarle barras al final, para ello usa template strings que recomendo @Víctor Hugo Lara Santillán en su respuesta.

Comment: Claro, procurare adjuntar datos siempre que se pueda, saludos

Comment: VSCODE dice que se puede modificar la propiedad "Editor: Max Tokenization Line Length" en Code->Preferences->Settings->Text Editor. Esto con la finalidad de modificar el line length, esta en 20000 x default.

Comment: @BetaM / Riven, Hay forma de cambiar el nombre de la pregunta? Debería llamarse "Modificar longitud de linea VSCODE", Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si dice que el tipo de retorno es `text/plain`, según el formato que planteas y lo que dices, dices que los datos almacenados son numericos, al inicio, cuando recibiste los datos sin formatearlos, debes haberlos recibido como una cadena de texto en la pagina, si estos numeros tenian un espacio, caracter o algo que los separase entre ellos, entonces puedes hacer algo tan fácil como lo siguiente:

- Primero ponle comillas al inicio y al final para convertir los numeros a string, que quede algo como esto:

`"2 4 5 3 1 8"` etc...

- Ahora ese texto guardalo en una variable:

`const misDatosComoString = '2 4 5 3 1 8';`

Ahora lo que puedes hacer es usar el texto dentro de comillas para formar un array dado un divisor, (un caracter o algo que separe cada numero entre sí):

```
const arregloNumeros = misDatosComoString.split(" ");
```

En tu caso el caracter divisor se trata de los espacios, así que tendras que tener cuidado con que al final siempre haya un espacio, si no pones un espacio al final de tu linea puede que algunos numeros se fusionen.

Una vez hecho esto, puedes convertir tus numeros que estan como cadenas de texto a numeros reales, pero esto no es necesario, ya que javascript toma los numeros como string, como si fueran numeros como tal, es decir que pese a que sea una cadena de texto, puedes hacer operaciones matematicas con ellos sin ningun problema, sin embargo aquí la forma de convertir rapidamente todos tus numeros que estan como cadenas de texto a un tipo `int`:

```
const arregloNumerosDeVerdad = arregloNumeros.map(num => num | 0);
```

Ahora bien, si quieres mantener por ejemplo puntos flotantes (numeros decimales), puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
const arregloNumerosFlotantes = arregloNumeros.map(num => parseFloat(num));
```

Comment: esto es lo que quiero hacer una vez que haya logrado pasar el texto a formato de cadena en VSCODE, pero gracias, esta perfectamente explicado.

Comment: Para pasar a formato de cadena solo debes ponerlo dentro de comillas... por supuesto luego guardar la cadena en una variable para tratarla.

Answer (score 0):

Para unir cada item dentro del arrray en una string simple, puede utilizar este ejemplo.

```
var a = ['Wind', 'Rain', 'Fire'];
var myVar1 = a.join(); // assigns 'Wind,Rain,Fire' to myVar1
var myVar2 = a.join(', '); // assigns 'Wind, Rain, Fire' to myVar2
var myVar3 = a.join(' + '); // assigns 'Wind + Rain + Fire' to myVar3
var myVar4 = a.join(''); // assigns 'WindRainFire' to myVar4
```

Tambien cuando necesites crear una string que abarque mas de una linea, puedes utilizar

```
var myString = `Esta es la linea 1
                   Esta es la linea 2`;
```

Comment: Tu segundo ejemplo es lo que estoy intentando, pero no me funciono, me parece que la cadena es muy larga. Saludos

Comment: No creo que sea la longitud, el maximo es como de 1GB, en VSCode busca donde cambia de color, el texto y talvez es que haya un caracter `. Si pudieras compartir el archivo podriamos revisarlo.